# Terminal: count "output-list"

Tags: list, shell, count, terminal, command

I am struggling with the following.
I run this command in terminal:

**airport en1 -s**

As a result I get a list of wifi networks looking smt like this:

```
SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
eduroam 00:25:84:36:b1:0d -76  40      N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:25:84:36:b1:0f -76  40      N  NL NONE
eduroam 00:17:df:2d:51:ad -80  36      N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:17:df:2d:51:af -81  36      N  NL NONE
eduroam 00:25:84:36:b1:02 -76  11      N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:25:84:36:b1:00 -76  11      N  NL NONE
interact c0:3f:0e:59:e2:0e -73  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
eduroam 00:25:84:36:d1:32 -73  6       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:25:84:36:d1:30 -73  6       N  NL NONE
Airtez 00:17:df:2d:51:a0 -73  1       N  NL NONE
Airtez 00:1c:f9:05:75:90 -76  1       N  NL NONE
eduroam 00:25:84:8f:53:12 -80  1       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
eduroam 00:25:84:36:d7:02 -73  1       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:25:84:36:d7:00 -73  1       N  NL NONE
eduroam 00:1c:f9:05:75:92 -76  1       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
Airtez 00:25:84:8f:53:10 -84  1       N  NL NONE
eduroam 00:1d:70:98:96:32 -87  1       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES) 
eduroam 00:17:df:2d:51:a2 -72  1       N  NL WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES)
```

Now I want the terminal to count the the list (without the first line)

I already tried: `**ls airport en1 -s**` but that does not work.
Also tried: `**grep -Rl "*keyword*" ./ | wc -l**`

Grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your command...|awk 'END{print NR--}'
```

will count lines without the first line. (total line number -1)

If you want to do some grep, you can do:

```
your command...|grep -c 'keyword'
```